# How make a link load in whole page instead of loading in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
            <option value="">...Select Paragraph...</option>
            <option value="page-1.html">Paragraph 1 </option>
            <option value="page-2.html">Paragraph 2 </option>
            <option value="page-3.html">Paragraph 3 </option>
            <option value="page-4.html">Paragraph 4 </option>
        </select>
```

I have used the above html code to create a drop-down menu. What it does is that whenever a user changes value of the dropdown, he is taken to another url. Because i have to use it in lot of another html pages, i created a seperate html page for it and embed it as an iframe wherever i need it. The problem I am facing is that whenever the user changes the value of the drop-down, the new url is loaded in the iframe instead of loading in the whole page. Please help!. What changes should I make in `onchange=""` that the url loads in parent page instead of iframe? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Not use `<iframe>` since this tag is for embedding a HTML inside another HTML, which I don't know why you want to, because you want it to be full-screen and not inside some other HTML content.
2. CSS the `<iframe>` with

   ```
   iframe {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes sir, I embed this dropdown menu into another html pages. I want users to select url from the dropdown if they want to go to particular url listed in the dropdown. but that url should not load in the iframe but in the whole page.

Comment: Yes, but when they click on that button, they are redirected to another URL, which is represented by another HTML page?

Comment: Yes sir. Dropdown container list of links of html pages which users can visit. I want to embed this dropdown as an iframe in lot of html pages. But when user changes the dropdown, the new url is loaded in the same iframe. I want the new url to load in the parent page

Answer (score 0):

Since you have embedded the drop down which is in completely separate page, you need to get the parent window while your drop down changes.

```
window.parent.document.href = this.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="callfun(this.value);">
    <option>...Select Paragraph...</option>
    <option value="paragraph1">Paragraph 1 </option>
    <option value="paragraph2">Paragraph 2 </option>
    <option value="paragraph3">Paragraph 3 </option>
    <option value="paragraph4">Paragraph 4 </option>
</select>
```

use JS to get the value of selected options like

```
function callfun(value) { 
    if(value == "paragraph1") { 
        // do something 
    } else if(value == "paragraph2") { 
        // do something 
    } else if(value == "paragraph3") { 
        // do something 
    } else { 
        // do something 
    } 
}
```

Comment: use JS to get the value of selected options like <script>
function callfun(value)
{
if(value == "paragraph1")
{
 do something
}
else if(value == "paragraph2")
{
 do something
}
else if(value == "paragraph3")
{
 do something
}
else
{
 do something
}

}

</script>